# Managing Sharepoint list items view permissions using JSOM

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-list

Is it possible to set view permissions to Sharepoint list items using just only JSOM? ie, userA can only view and edit list items submitted by themselves. Owner of the site should be able to view and edit all list items.

Am struggling the idea of setting permissions from the 'porous' client-side codes. I mean, what's stopping a clever user from changing permissions for another user via the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to set the following setting by JSOM?

[image]

Comment: Permissions should be set at the point when listItem is created by my enduser. Item created by my enduser should be visible only to himself and the owner of the list.

Comment: Am struggling the idea of setting permissions from the 'porous' client-side codes. I mean, what's stopping a clever user from changing permissions for another user via the console?

Comment: Ooo... I see... "Read items that were created by the user"? "Create items and edit items that were created by the user"? That looks applicable to my scenario.

Comment: I do have another requirement that is the user who created the listItem is able to grant edit and read accesses to specific users in the organization. Again this must be via JSOM only and no server side codes